# jQuery IE7 bug on multiple .hide listeners

Tags: jquery, gridview, hide, show

I'm building a product page, can be seen here (http://n9nemedia.net/v2/products/), and the script in a singular fashion (not hiding multiple divs with one listener works perfect - can be seen here http://www.supercentral.net/downloads by clicking on "Read List" under Zombie Map Pack) works perfectly.

My question is, what can I do to make (http://www.n9nemedia.net/v2/products/) work in IE7?

Code example:

```
jQ(".prod-details-web").hide();
jQ(".prod-details-dev").hide();
jQ(".prod-details-grow").hide();
jQ(".prod-details-brand").hide();
jQ(".prod-details-3g").hide();  
jQ(".prod-expand-web").click(function(event) {
    jQ(".prod-details-dev").slideUp("fast");
    jQ(".prod-details-grow").slideUp("fast");
    jQ(".prod-details-brand").slideUp("fast");
    jQ(".prod-details-3g").slideUp("fast");                               
    jQ(this).parents(".prodcontent")
        .find(".prod-details-web").slideDown("slow");
});
jQ(".prod-collapse-web").click(function(event) {
    jQ(this).parents(".prod-details-web").slideUp("fast");
    event.preventDefault();
    jQ(".prod-details-web:hidden").show();
});
```

The objective is to show only one product per one click. Not to un-hide all divs on click. The script is working perfectly in all browsers but IE7. Working in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE8 *that I've checked personally.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Changed:

jQ(this).parents(".prodcontent")
        .find(".prod-details-web").slideDown("slow");
});

to:

jQ(this).parents(".prodcontent")
        .find(".prod-details-web").show("slow");
});

and now it's working in IE7 flawlessly.

This worked great until I cleared my cache and found a funky behavior in Chrome and Safari. Conditional statement is needed on top of this if you'd like to keep the same animation fluid amongst browsers

```
    /*@cc_on @*/
    /*@if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
    .find(".prod-details-web").show("slow");
    @else @*/
    .find(".prod-details-web").slideDown("slow");
    /*@end @*/
```